# Time complexity of finding out if two nodes have a edge between

Tags: graph, time-complexity

I'm trying to calculate the complexity of a algorithm to solve this problem:

Given a undirected graph (stored with adjacency list) and two nodes, i need to find out if there is a edge between them.

The solution i'm trying to get the complexity is to search on the graph for the first node and then search on its adjacency list to the other one.

What would be the Big O time complexity of this algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly O(n), where n is the number of nodes in the graph, because you can always do a simple linear search for both search operations you mention.

In certain special cases you could prove an even lower bound. For example, if the nodes are ordered, it would be O(log(n)), because you could use a binary search algorithm.

Comment: Ok, Im sorry to bother. But i still dont get it.
Lets assume the node u im that i'm looking for its the last one from the nodes list. So it will have iterated n times. And now, assume that this node u has the maximum degree (n-1) and the node v i'm searching for is last in this list too, and would iterate n-1 times. In this worst case it would have complexity of n^2? I'm thinking it would be n*(n-1). Is this wrong?

Comment: But you only have to find two nodes, one after the other, so it's not O(n^2), but just O(n+n), which equals O(n).

Comment: Oh, i get it! As it's not indented it's a + not a *. Thank you very much!